# Inferring parameter of most template objects, but being explicit with others when calling a template function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I've noticed that modern C++ (C++11 etc..) can sometimes infer an `int` template parameter for a template object when passed to a function without explicitly passing the `int` value using angle braces.

But, what if I want a functions argument:

```
bitset<N_OLD>
```

to have the `int` template parameter inferred automatically as a function input, and the function return value:

```
bitset<N_NEW>
```

to be explicitly specified when invoking the function using angle braces or casing. Is this possible?  Example:

```
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

// expand or truncate bitset without sign extension
template<int N_NEW, int N_OLD> 
bitset<N_NEW>
bresize(const bitset<N_OLD> value)
{
    return bitset<N_NEW> {value.to_ullong() & ((1<<N_NEW)-1) }; 
}
```

For instance is it possible:

```
bitset<16> x {0xABCD};

// version explicit everything (Not what I want)
auto y2 = bresize<32, 16>(x); 

//Inference Attempt #1
auto  y1 = bresize<32>(x); 

//Inference Attempt #2
bitset<32> y3 = bresize(x);

//Inference Attempt #3
auto y4 = (bitset<32>)bresize(x);
```

I just want to understand what the rules are when inferring a template size parameter in the scenario stated above. The goal is to infer as much as possible regarding the input size of the `bitset` but to be explicit about the output size. Is this possible in C++11?

Comment: what do you mean when you say *width*?

Comment: width refers to the width parameter to the bitset.  For example, for bitset<N> the width is N.  and the template parameter is template<int N>

Comment: I see. Your question is confusing because templates have template parameters, not width. In the case of `std::bitset` it's first and only template parameter represents width. But you cannot say "width of most template objects" because that makes no sense. I am just trying to help you make your question clear.

Comment: ok.  it think I fixed it.

Comment: except the title :p

Answer (score 3):

I will give a generic answer then I will show you how to apply that to your case.

Template parameters cannot be deduced from the return type alone.

### Example 1

```
template <class T, class R>
auto foo(T) -> R;
```

`R` can **never** be deduced. So you need to be always explicit when calling `foo`.

Because `R` is after `T` in the template parameters this means you need to also specify `T` when specifying `R`, even  though `T` is deductible, e.g. `foo<int, double>(24)`.

The solution is pretty easy: put the non-deducible template parameters first:

```
template <class R, class T>
auto bar(T) -> R;
```

and you can call it like this:

```
bar<double>(24); // R explicit to double, T deduced as int from the parameters
```

## Example 2

```
template <class T, class U>
auto foo(T, U) -> U
```

Here `U` can be deduced because it can be deduced from the parameters.

## Example 3

If the non-deductible template parameter is dependent on another deductible template parameter then you can *compute* it from the deductible parameter:

```
template <class T>
auto foo(T) -> std::decay_t<T>
```

## Your case

First the template argument type for `std::bitset` is `std::size_t` and not `int`. This alone will cause deduction problems. Fix this first.

The next thing to make sure is to have the non-deductible template parameter first:

```
template<std::size_t N_NEW, std::size_t N_OLD> 
std::bitset<N_NEW>
bresize(std::bitset<N_OLD> value) { /* ... */ }
```

Then you can call `bresize` as:

```
bresize<32>(x);
```

Moreover if `N_NEW` can be `constexpr` computed from `N_OLD` then you can skip the explicit parameter altogether:

```
template<std::size_t N_OLD> 
std::bitset<N_OLD * 2>
bresize(std::bitset<N_OLD> value) { /* ... */ }
```

or

```
template<std::size_t N_OLD, std::size_t N_NEW = N_OLD * 2> 
std::bitset<N_NEW>
bresize(std::bitset<N_OLD> value) { /* ... */ }
```

or

```
constexpr auto new_width(std::size_t old_width) => std::size_t
{
    return old_width * 2;
    /* or any constexpr allowed body */
};

template<std::size_t N_OLD> 
std::bitset<new_width(N_OLD)>
bresize(std::bitset<N_OLD> value) { /* ... */ }
```

or

```
template<std::size_t N_OLD, std::size_t N_NEW = new_width(N_OLD)> 
std::bitset<N_NEW>
bresize(std::bitset<N_OLD> value) { /* ... */ }
```

---

Some minor off-topic nitpicking: `const T` as a parameter doesn't make much sense.
Use either `const T&` or `T`.